# In doubt with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for complex numbers

Tags: solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I just want to hear from you if I am understanding it correctly. No proofs here, just yes or no.

It is well-know that, if $a_i,b_i$ are complex numbers, then
$$
\left | \sum_{i}a_i\overline{b_i} \right |^2\leq \sum_{i}\left | a_i \right |^2\sum_{i}\left | b_i \right |^2
$$
Would this still hold, if we replace $\overline{b_i}$ with $b_i$? Or, using this inequality, could we then say that
$$
\left | \sum_{i}a_ib_i \right |^2=\left | \sum_{i}a_i\overline{(\overline{b_i})} \right |^2\leq \sum_{i}\left | a_i \right |^2\sum_{i}\left | \overline{b_i} \right |^2=\sum_{i}\left | a_i \right |^2\sum_{i}\left | b_i \right |^2?
$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks. The reason why the first question is true, is because of the last question, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right for the right reasons.